# Change page to use minimal.master?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010. I edit mypage.aspx and change the first line from MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" to MasterPageFile="~masterurl/minimal.master" to use a different master page for the page.

When I save changes and then visit the page, I get:

**Error 
The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: 0f774212-4f09-45f0-bc06-59406f2db725 
Date and Time: 06/02/2013 15:38:52**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use another replaceable token with miminal.master (~masterurl won't work), so use:

```
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master
```

for site collection and

```
~site/_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master
```

for master page on a site

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried both, on a page in the top level site of the site collection. Got UNEXPECTED ERROR both times.

Comment: You may see UNEXPECTED ERROR because on your page you are using ContentPlaceHolder which is not specified in `minimal.master` (For example `PlaceHolderLeftActions`). Could you please find error in ULS log by correlation Id and provide full message and stack trace?

Comment: OK, I found the ULS log. How do I find the stack trace?

Comment: Refresh the page with an error, as the result new correlation Id will be generated, find recent log by modified date and search inside by correlation Id

Comment: Thanks. I managed to view the ULS log and see which Placeholders were causing the problem. Then I found a simpler solution to havng a minimal page. In the end, I copied v4.master to blank.master. Edited blank.master and hid the parts of the page I didn't want with **style="display:none"**. Then set mypage.aspx to use blank.master as its master page.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it either with attach command or change in directly in one place of code.

[image]